# i want to make this page responsive how can i do say

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: I want to make this mobile responsive]

**I want to make this mobile responsive**

The button are overlaping

```
{%load static%}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Upload_Image</title>
      <style>
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background: #7abecc !important;
        }


    .material-icons {
                vertical-align: middle;

        }
        .container2{
        padding-left: 40%;

        }
    .alert{
            padding-left: 40%;

        }




        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% if user.is_authenticated%}
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Image Captioning</a>
          <i class="material-icons bg-light ">collections</i>
         

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
             
            </ul>
            <span class="navbar-text">
              <a href="/caption/" class="btn btn-link  "style="margin-right:10px;text-decoration:none;">WRITE CAPTION</a>
              <a href=""class="btn btn-danger my-2 mx-3"style="width:130px;height:36px;">Hi! {{ user.username }}</a>


             
              
              <a href="/index"><i class="material-icons bg-dark mx-2  ">home</i></a>
            <a href="/logout/"><i class="material-icons bg-dark mx-3 ">logout</i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </nav>

    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <h1>Image Upload</h1>
              </div>
    
   
      <form method="post"action="/upload_save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {%csrf_token%}
        <div class="container"style="height:1000px;Max-width:100%;">
        <div  class ="container2"  id ="images"><br>
         
       <input type="button"class="btn btn-success cc"name="add_image" id ="add_image"value="Add Image">
      
       <input type="submit"class="btn btn-success"value="Upload & Save Data"><br>
       <!-- <input type="submit"class="btn btn-primary"value="Save Data"> -->
    </div>
    </form>
    
    <script>
        document.getElementById("add_image").onclick=function (ev) {
           
            var image=document.getElementById("images");
            var preview=document.createElement("img");
             preview.style.width="300px";
            preview.style.height="300px";
            preview.style.marginTop = "20px";
            preview.style.border = "thick solid #ffffff";
            preview.style.borderRadius = "25px";
    
    
            var newInput=document.createElement("input");
            newInput.type="file";
            newInput.name="file[]";
            
            var br=document.createElement("br");
            var br1=document.createElement("br");
    
            newInput.onchange=function(ev1){
                if(this.files && this.files[0])
                {
                    var fileReader=new FileReader();
                    fileReader.onload=function(ev2){
                        preview.src=ev2.target.result;
    
                    };
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0])
                }
            };
           
            image.appendChild(newInput)
            image.appendChild(preview);
            image.appendChild(br);
            image.appendChild(br1);
    
        }
        </script>
        
    {%else%}
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("Cant Access without Login");
      window.location.href = "{%url 'login' %}"
  </script>
    {% endif %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**This the code of my HTML file and i want to make it mobile responsive here the image preview option are going out of the screeen**

i tried many things but nothing works so i have no idea what to do next how to resolve the issue

*When using Bootstrap’s source Sass files, you have the option of using Sass variables and mixins to create custom, semantic, and responsive page layouts. Our predefined grid classes use these same variables and mixins to provide a whole suite of ready-to-use classes for fast responsive layouts.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi hacakaman79 just add below code on head style tag

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  form{
       width : 100%;
       margin : 0 auto;
       clear : both;
     }
     .container2{
      padding : 0; 
      margin : 0 auto;
     }
  }
```